# Google Analytics: Combine event and pageview

Tags: javascript, ember.js, google-analytics

I am looking for a solution to combine an event with a pageview in Google Analytics (Universal Analytics).

It is needed for an Ember.js application with redundant navigation (sidebar and tab-navigation). To find out which navigation is used more frequent I want to track all clicks on the buttons. First I send an event like this from the action handler of the button: `ga('send', 'event', 'tab-button', 'click', 'home');`

The application controller sends a pageview when the path changes:

```
currentPathDidChange: function() {

  App.set('currentPath', this.get('currentPath'));

  Ember.run.next(function(){
    var loc = window.location,
        page = loc.hash ? loc.hash.substring(1) : loc.pathname + loc.search;
    App.set('currentUrl', page);
    ga('send', 'pageview', '/home');
  });
}.observes('currentPath')
```

Now sometimes (probably because of the asynchronous handling) the event is processed after the pageview, wich sets the "Active Page" to "/". I also tried to set a path-property to the event-tracking, but I think the wrong order of processing will still distort the "Behavior-Flow"

Is there any way to send the pageview combined with the event of the clicked button as a single tracking-data, or any other solution? As result I need a correct flow like:

1. Pageview: page-1
2. Event:    menu-button-2
3. Pageview: page-2

Comment: Haven't tested this, but can't you send the event in a hit callback to the pageview (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback) ?

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff: Thank you for your suggestion. I think using the callback of the event-tracking to send the pageview would be a working. I found another solution that works well for me. I defined a custom dimension 'navigation-type' with 'hit-scope'. Whenever a tab or menu button is clicked, i set this to 'menu-navigation' or 'tab-navigation'

Answer (score 0):

**hcbartel**, another suggestion is to use event-flow which could give you a much more detailed information.

Basically you would need to "translate" all requests to events and then filter only those that are relevant to navigation in a special profile/view, but then you would be able to see the exact flow for various user groups.